# rails changed? returns true though it should not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm importing data via rake task from a CSV-file into a Rails 3.2.14 App (under Ruby 2.0.0), like so:

```
CSV.foreach("import.txt", col_sep: ";", encoding: "ISO8859-1:UTF-8") do |row|
    v = Variant.where(:sku => row[1]).first  
    unless v.nil?                                 
      p = v.product                                 
    else
      p = Product.new()                  
    end
    p.name = row[2]
    p.sku = row[1]
    p.description = row[3] + row[4]
    if p.changed?
      if p.save
        puts "Product #{p.name} created"
      else
        p.errors.each do |error|
          puts error
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I only want to store the new values into db, when something has changed, but changed?-method always return true.

```
p.name == row[2] #=> true
p.name.class == row[2].class #=> true
```

but:

```
p.name = row[2]
p.changed? #=> true
```

So how can changed? return true? The docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html
say:

> Assigning the same value leaves the attribute unchanged:
>
> person.name = 'Bill'
>
> person.name_changed?  # => false
>
> person.name_change    # => nil

What am I missing?

Comment: I am wondering if your sku and description might have changed.

Comment: What does `p.name_changed?` return?

Comment: You can inspect the changes with `p.changes`, it returns a hash in the form `{attribute => [old_value, new_value]}`

Comment: @Stefan: `p.name_changed?` also returns true. `.changes` returns the name with two identical strings.

Comment: To be clear, does `p.changes` show a hash of all 3 of the attributes (`name`, `sku`, `description`) with identical old and new values?

Comment: @EmperorJK maybe they just look identical, compare them character-wise with `p.name_change.map(&:chars)` and `p.name_change.map(&:bytes)`

Comment: can you show the names that are same but still show as changed? also does it happen for all cases or only few?

Comment: Yes, this behaviour is absolutly reproducible and happens on every product when calling from rake task and when calling from console: `p.name #=> "Testproduct"` then `p.product = "Testproduct"` and `p.name_changed? #=> true` as well as `p.changed? #=> true`

Comment: @mbratch: Yes it does include all those attributes. @Stefan: `p.name_change.map(&:chars)
 => [["T", "e", "s", "t", "p", "r", "o", "d", "u", "c", "t"], ["T", "e", "s", "t", "p", "r", "o", "d", "u", "c", "t"]]` and `p.name_change.map(&:bytes)
 => [[84, 101, 115, 116, 112, 114, 111, 100, 117, 99, 116], [84, 101, 115, 116, 112, 114, 111, 100, 117, 99, 116]]`

Comment: @EmperorJK I know it includes the attributes. My question is if you are seeing `p.changes` give an "old" == "new" for every attribute.

Comment: @EmperorJK I have no idea why Rails considers this a change, both strings are identical (at the byte level).

Comment: Did the code call `name_will_change!` in the writer accessor for p?

Comment: is there any custom method for `p.name=` in your model?

Comment: I'm using parts of Spree and other gems. I think I'll have to review Spree's and the other gem's code and look for changes to these methods. I tried with a fresh rails app yesterday evening and everything works as it should.